# How can I debug a crash from the call to the undo command on a NSMenuItem?

Tags: macos, cocoa, crash, undo

I would like to be able to fix this crash on my OSX application, I've been seeing the crashes on my firebase console when users perform an undo action, from what I can see probably from a key command. But I have no idea why & where in the app is this happening.

```
   Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x7fff6c60981d objc_msgSend + 29
1  Foundation                     0x7fff360047a7 -[_NSUndoStack popAndInvoke] + 187
2  Foundation                     0x7fff36004514 -[NSUndoManager undoNestedGroup] + 296
3  AppKit                         0x7fff30ff5d49 -[NSCellUndoManager undo] + 102
4  AppKit                         0x7fff30d36437 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 299
5  AppKit                         0x7fff30e46aee -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 312
6  AppKit                         0x7fff30e4686a -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 106
7  AppKit                         0x7fff30e45767 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 412
8  AppKit                         0x7fff3127b27b routeKeyEquivalent + 521
9  AppKit                         0x7fff30c974dd -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1161
10 AppKit                         0x7fff30ae421f -[NSApplication run] + 707
11 AppKit                         0x7fff30ab5ff6 NSApplicationMain + 777
12 libdyld.dylib                  0x7fff6d7bdcc9 start + 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, debugging inside Apple's own code is difficult.  The obvious question, then, is: what are you doing with undo in your app's code?  If the answer is "nothing", then Apple's own code is handling undo wrong and crashing, so congrats, you've found a bug, log it on Apple's bug reporter and move on.  If, on the other hand, you're interacting with the undo system in your own code, then that would be where you'd look for the bug, obviously, but since you've said nothing at all about that, it's rather hard for us to guess.

Comment: Thank you, but Im not doing any handling of undo besides marking NSTextView's to handle their own undo.